# How does one determine the date a constructed language was invented?

Tags: conlang-creation, history

Some constructed languages list a date, or at least year, of creation. Is there any official or unofficial standard to determine that date for any given conlang? The way I see it, there are several possibilities, at least the ones I thought up:

- The date that work began on the language
- The date of the first evidence of work on the language, if the prior date is not known
- The date of the first usage of the language (this could be broken down into public *or* private usage)
- The date of the first publication that mentions the language
- The publication date of the first dictionary and/or grammar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For auxiliary languages it's usually publication date of the first grammar/dictionary released to the public or the first work dedicated to the language, whichever comes first.

For Esperanto this was *Unua Libro*, which was published in 1887 - more than a year after Zamenhof began working on the language. Wikipedia also lists the year of creation of Occidental as 1922, the year de Wahl published the first edition of the *Kosmoglotta* magazine, despite there being evidence that the language was used much before then, both in private conversation (letters etc.) and even a publication written entirely in Occidental.

The "date of creation" for other types of conlangs seems to be less well-defined, although I'd expect that fictional languages would be associated with the publication of the first book/movie/game that uses them (perhaps with the exception of Tolkien's languages). Wikipedia also uses the day Lojban began being developed as its creation date.